# Passing strings between classes and methods

Tags: java

I've been trying to pass a string from a method in one class to a method in another class, but can't seem to do it.

I've been trying a couple of things like

```
String location = Latitude + "," + Longitude;
AccelOrientExample GPSstring = new AccelOrientExample();
GPSstring.onSensorChanged(location);
```

where location is the string I want to pass to the class AccelOrientExample, where I have a method with a arguement for location.

Please help, thanks

Cannot instantiate the type AccelOrientExample is the first error I get which is on the new side. And The method onSensorChanged(SensorEvent) in the type SensorEventListener is not applicable for the arguments (String) on the second line.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent, String location)
```

Is the method in the AccelOrientExample

Comment: What errors do you get? *How* does this not work?

Comment: What is the problem are you facing?

Comment: `Can't seem to do it`.. Then what is happening?

Comment: `Latitude`, `Longitude` and `GPSstring` are variables. It is recommended practice in Java to start their names with lowercase characters.

Comment: show us `onSensorChanged` method..

Comment: We don't really have enough information to be able to answer this.

Comment: Are you seriously not able to figure out what went wrong? Clearly your method accepts 2 arguments and you are passing just one.

Comment: updated with more info, hopefully there is enough there now

Comment: Also, your `AccelOrientExample` might be an abstract class or an `interface`. That's why you cannot instantiate it.

Comment: @RohitJain Yes it is an absrtact class, as it was giving me a error to either do that or to implement used methods, which were used in the other class so I thought that might be a better option. I've created a new class called logger and passed the strings to that instead of to the accel class and its not giving me any errors, so hopefully that is better. Thanks for your input.

Comment: My advice: pause this project and follow a basic course on programming in Java.

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot instantiate the type AccelOrientExample is the first error I
>   get which is on the new side.

I think your **AccelOrientExample** is an Abstract class. you cant instantiate your Abstract class with new operator. you will have to let your subclass(concrete class) to initialize it.

like lets assume AccelOrientedExampleImpl is the subclass of AccelOrientedExample class.

then ,

```
           AccelOrientExample GPSstring  = new AccelOrientedExampleImpl();
```

> The method onSensorChanged(SensorEvent) in the type
>   SensorEventListener is not applicable for the arguments (String) on
>   the second line.

your method signature takes two arguments, SensorEvent instance and a String.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent, String location)
```

you are trying to pass only String instance.you have to pass both as your method expects two arguments. do something like below, i am assuming the **SensorEvent** is a concrete class.

```
String location = Latitude + "," + Longitude;
AccelOrientExample GPSstring = new AccelOrientExample();
GPSstring.onSensorChanged(new SensorEvent(), location);
```

Comment: Also, OP can't instantiate `AccelOrientExample` according to the exception he posted.

Comment: @RohitJain check my edit, i am assuming AccelOrientedExample is a abstract class. please lemme know if i am missing anything else)

Comment: Now it's a complete answer. As per the current question, OP can accept this as answer. :)

Comment: The sensor event is to monitor the accel sensor so it is in that class. I've created another class logger to log the values so hopefully it is better. Also, changing gpsString to (null, location) hopefully is another to to it. If not please let me know.

Comment: @jaclsparrow can you clear your second point of changing  gpsString to (null, location) please .:)

Comment: well its more the intelisense that suggests null along with all the other variables. So I'm passing the first arguement as a null and location as the second. And in a different class I'm doing the opposite, passing data as the first and null as the second. I know I'm kinda gone out from the spec of the question, sorry

Comment: you cant do that for the same method unless you overload the method.